# Why does attaching a non-root EBS drive created from a snapshot not maintain the partitions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

When I create a snapshot of an auxiliary RHEL8 EC2 root volume, I can then create a new EBS device from the snapshot. I have a need to attach the new available EBS snapshot as a secondary drive on my running RHEL8 EC2 instance. When I attach the EBS drive created from the snapshot, I'm seeing the root partition is no longer present on the disk. Here is a look at the lsblk configuration after attaching the secondary disk:

```bash
[root@ip-172-31-76-220 ec2-user]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0   10G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0  200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0  512M  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0  9.3G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:1    0   10G  0 disk
```

Please note, /dev/nvme1n1 disk has no partitions, when this drive was created from a RHEl8 root device. I'm expecting at least one partition with the root OS present.

If I create a new auxiliary RHEL8 instance, stop the instance and detach the drive, I can then attach the available drive to my running EC2 instance and am able to see the OS partitions as expected. In the following lsblk config, the /dev/nvme2n1 disk retains the OS disk partitions.

```bash
[root@ip-172-31-76-220 ec2-user]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0   10G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0  200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0  512M  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0  9.3G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:1    0   10G  0 disk
nvme2n1     259:6    0   10G  0 disk
├─nvme2n1p1 259:7    0  200M  0 part
├─nvme2n1p2 259:8    0  512M  0 part
└─nvme2n1p3 259:9    0  9.3G  0 part
```

Comment: I don't see a `nvme3n1` disk anywhere?

Comment: fixed the typo in the disk name

Answer (score 0):

After taking a break for a few days, I noticed a bug in my create-snapshot cli command where I didn't supply the snapshot-id parameter. So unsurprisingly, the blank disk had no partitions.